# How do I properly block code execution until callback

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, callback

I am new to Unity and C# and trying to query my Firebase Realtime Database, but the code does not block for the callback to finish.

I have tried implementing callbacks but this does not seem to work.

```
static public void ReadFromDb(int level, Action<int> callback) 
{
    int return_value = -1;
    string sessionId = PlayerPrefs.GetString("SessionID");

    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("users/"+sessionId).GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
        if (task.IsFaulted) 
        {
            // Handle the error...
            Debug.Log("Task faulted");
            callback(return_value);
        } 
        else if (task.IsCompleted) 
        {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
            string score_string = (snapshot.Child(level.ToString()).Value).ToString();
            Debug.Log("score_string " + score_string);
            return_value = int.Parse(score_string);
            callback(return_value);
        }
    });
}


public void LevelComplete() 
{
    DatabaseCode.writeDatabase(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1, counter);
    DatabaseCode.ReadFromDb(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1, (result) => {
        prevlevelscore = result;
        Debug.Log("result " + result.ToString());
    });
    prevscore = prevlevelscore;
    Debug.Log("Returned value: " + prevlevelscore.ToString());
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
}
```

In `LevelComplete()`, `Debug.Log("Returned value: " + prevlevelscore.ToString());` executes before `prevlevelscore = result;`
I want to make sure that the value of `prevlevelscore` is updated before executing `Debug.Log`.

Comment: well because it is not part of the callback ... you should place `Debug.Log("Returned value: " + prevlevelscore.ToString());` inside the callback if it shall be part of the delayed code ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the rest of the code inside the callback too:

```
public void LevelComplete() 
{
    DatabaseCode.writeDatabase(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1, counter);
    DatabaseCode.ReadFromDb(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1, (result) => {
        Debug.Log("result " + result.ToString());
        prevscore = result;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
    });    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your ReadFromDb method returns before being finished. You can solve this issue by putting all your code in the callback (but you won't be able to do that all the time) or you can use the async await pattern.

Make ReadFromDb async:

```
    static public async Task ReadFromDb(int level, Action<int> callback) 
    {
        int return_value = -1;
        string sessionId = PlayerPrefs.GetString("SessionID");

        await FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("users/"+sessionId).GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
            if (task.IsFaulted) 
            {
                // Handle the error...
                Debug.Log("Task faulted");
                callback(return_value);
            } 
            else if (task.IsCompleted) 
            {
                DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
                string score_string = (snapshot.Child(level.ToString()).Value).ToString();
                Debug.Log("score_string " + score_string);
                return_value = int.Parse(score_string);
                callback(return_value);
            }
        });
    }
```

Note the await keywork before your `GetValueAsync().ContinueWith` because this precise code is asynchronous and needs to be awaited if you want to hold code execution until the result has been fetched.

And in your caller:

```
    public async Task LevelComplete() 
    {
        DatabaseCode.writeDatabase(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1, counter);
        await DatabaseCode.ReadFromDb(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1, (result) => {
            prevlevelscore = result;
            Debug.Log("result " + result.ToString());
        });
        prevscore = prevlevelscore;
        Debug.Log("Returned value: " + prevlevelscore.ToString());
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
    }
```

This method becomes async as well (because asynchronicity propagates). Again, the await keyword will hold on execution until the readFromDb method has finished. Which means that your data will be ready.

Comment: you probably would want to rather make `LevelComplete()` an `public async void` .. otherwise you should explain how OP can actually call and use the `public async Task LevelComplete()`

Comment: `public async void` is a Task antipattern. Check https://markheath.net/post/async-antipatterns for further info.

Comment: It is controversial but the only way to actually start calling the `async` chain ... you uusally don't do it since you will never know when the call finishes .... in your case using a callback pattern anyway it doesn't matter since thanks to the callback you know when the call is finished. As said .. if not using it explain otherwise how OP should ever start invoking the `async` methods. See the second part in your link `So it's not necessarily a problem`